# gitignore not included in cloned repo

Tags: html, git, twitter-bootstrap

I just cloned bootstrap and I noticed in the repo there are a few files that are missing from my local clone: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

The files missing from my local are:

```
.editorconfig
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.travis.yml
```

Why? Also, how can I make it so that when I compile my app running 'grunt', that the files in my source control are unaffected by the compile. Running that command creates so many different folders and files it often makes my source control client crash.

Thanks.

Comment: Check whether you're showing hidden files

Comment: As far as your second question, the `.gitignore` file should ignore any files created during compilation.

Comment: yes I am showing hidden files, i ls-la'd the directory and they are not there

Comment: @DaveZych ok thanks, originally i didnt have a git ignore because it didnt clone for whatever reason and it messed me up!